# onResume method not working for Twitter Implementation

Tags: android, twitter

Trying to integrate Twitter with my app. Followed the tutorials, but it is not working.

I have a `PreferenceActivity` that has a `CheckBoxPreference`. If clicked, I do the following:

```
chkTwitter.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {           
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference _pref) {
        Intent fbIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TwitterConnectActivity.class);
        _pref.setIntent(fbIntent);
        return false;
    }
});
```

My TwitterConnectActivity is invoked, I configure the Oauth object there and invoke Twitter's authentication website.

When I click on Authorize App, my `onResume` is invoked:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (this.getIntent()!=null && this.getIntent().getData()!=null){
            Uri uri = this.getIntent().getData();

            if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(CALLBACK_URL)) {
                String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(oauth.signpost.OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);
```

The problem is that `this.getIntent().getData()` is null, so I never go inside the if condition.

My AndroidManifest looks like this:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="my_twitter" android:scheme="callback" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TwitterConnectActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
```

Most certainly I defined my Callback URL like: `private String CALLBACK_URL =           "callback://my_twitter";`

Anyone can help me out?

Cheers,
Felipe

Comment: +1 for teaching me a clever little trick to dynamically set the `Intent` of a `Preference` using the click handler :)

Comment: I have no idea if I'm right about this since I haven't added Twitter to an app in a while, but could it be that you need to use onNewIntent?

Comment: Glad I helped @Devunwired :)
Catherine the oneNewIntent method will be invoked depending on how I use the launchMode property there, and I am just using the normal one, so I don't think onNewIntent is invoked. I will take a look!

Comment: Very, very strange... I haven't done anything and now the data in the Intent is coming. Well, alright then!

Answer (score 0):

use StartActivityForResult instead.